# Generating JAXB components for WSDL using org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: spring-ws, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am trying to follow the example given at http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service, ofcourse, with the WSDL of my own. However, I am unable to see any JAXB classes being generated. There are no errors or useful debug information either.

What are the limitations or WSDL constructs that above example would not work?

Let me know if you need any further information.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

check your pom, there should be something along these line:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version> <!-- I used version 0.8.1 since 0.8.2 is bugged and it throws the Exception 
                "Illegal pattern character 'g' "when using italian locale -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>wsdl-generation</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>*.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <!-- Specify binding directory where we put customization for the 
                            generated classes -->
                        <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/binding</bindingDirectory>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <include>*.xjb</include>
                        </bindingIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

with slight difference to match with your wsdl location/binding (if any)/etc..
Classes are generated under target, so ensure that you add them to the classpath (simply after you run the generate sources, do a maven -->update project and it should take care of it if i recall correctly)..
You might want to do a right click --> run as --> maven generate sources in case it seems it's not working properly.